# MySQL, SQL error (1305) procedure does not exist

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hello, everybody.

I am using MariaDB 10.0.23 in CentOS 7.

I've dumped db (include routines) using mysqldump and restore it on window 7 system. Window system is using same MariaDB version.

All data is OK. The only problem is stored procedures. When I see 'Procedures' in HeidiSQL, I can see all the procedures. But when I tried to call or alter or drop procedure, below error occurs.

SQL Error (1305): PROCEDURE sp_name does not exist

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

What's wrong with my DB?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Could you run SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES to see if your procedures are listed there? There is a column named ROUTINE_DEFINITION that contains your procedure body.

Comment: @Hermanto I've input the query that you suggested and I can see all the procedures in its result. And in 'ROUTINE_DEFINITION' column, there's procedure body. I've tried to call procedures in MySQL console, the result was same. I think this is not the problem of HeidiSQL.

Comment: How about SELECT * FROM MYSQL.PROC? Does this query produce same number of procedure as the first?

Comment: @Hermanto I added 'type' and 'db' in WHERE condition to your query. And yes, 42 procedures on the results. (You can see 42 procedures count in screenshot.)

Comment: On your screenshot, there is a text "You have no privilege to this routine". Are you root or user that has privileges to access the procedure? I tried to create a minimal user without privileges on my server and try to alter SP that I know it exists and resulted in same error message like yours. Looks like this is about privileges. Sorry for too much asking.

Comment: @Hermanto No!! your advice gives great help to me. I'll check the privileges part!! Thank you~!!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127604/discussion-between-hermanto-and-passion053).